# No se puede redirigir después de enviar los encabezados HTTP. en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, .net

Tengo una pagina de paso para poder descargar un archivo excel de tipo web form, donde coloco el codigo siguiente:

```html
                    string ruta = (string)Session["RutaArchivo"];
                    string nombreA = (string)Session["NombreArchivo"];
                FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.Open);
                float FileSize;
                FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
                byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
                sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length);
                sourceFile.Close();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application / vnd.ms - excel";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", getContent.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreA);
                Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);

                if (File.Exists(ruta))
                    File.Delete(ruta);

                Session["RutaArchivo"] = null;
                Session["NombreArchivo"] = null;

                Response.Flush();
                Response.Redirect("CargaArchivo.aspx");
```

y si descarga el archivo, pero el problema que tengo es que no puedo redireccionar a la pagina desde donde tengo mis controles ya que me aparece el siguiente error, debugueando me doy cuenta que hace la excepcion desde la ultima linea >> Response.Redirect("CargaArchivo.aspx"); y la pagina se queda en blanco

> No se puede redirigir después de enviar los encabezados HTTP.

Comment: Hola, entiendo, pero creo que esta mal planteado el formato descarga, despues de hacer un flush, no se puede hacer nada mas, lo que te recomendaria, es que quites el redirect, y cuando pongas el link para descargar le pongas al <a href="paginadescarga.aspx" target="_blank">Link</a>, de esa manera no va a redireccionar y lo podrias hacer mediante javascript

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver pero entonces redireccionaría con JS? tienes un ejemplo?

Comment: hay bastantes ejemplos la web para ese tema, ejemplo https://aprende-a-programar.com/b/ASP-NET-descargar-archivo-desde-el-servidor/

Comment: Hola, igual te está a cuenta cargar la pagina de paso (la que descarga) en un iframe oculto en CargaArchivo.aspx, y así no tienes que hacer redirecciones